# Why does top of plug on power cord for Frigidaire refrigerator smell but doesn't get warm when plugged in?

Tags: electrical

There seems to be a smell coming from the top of the plug on a power cord for my Frigidaire refrigerator, but it isn't warm or hot.

Comment: maybe the plug touched something smelly ... why do you want the plug to get warm?

Comment: Is it a new fridge, did it just start smelling?  Molded plastic/rubber often has a smell. what type of smell?